# Outputting python notebook input and output to stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

How can one output and inputs from python notebook onto stackoverflow?  I see many people show their python code by displaying the full python notebook input and output including the 'In' and 'Out' prompts.

I can output just the python code by using the `%save` command but I have not found a way to include all of the data.

Comment: Could you reference another post that does that, to understand exactly what you mean?

Comment: {a samiple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295329/fastest-way-to-copy-columns-from-one-dataframe-to-another-using-pandas/21296133?iemail=1&noredirect=1#21296133) of what I'm talking about

Answer (score 4):

do you mean this?

```
In [62]: 1
Out[62]: 1

In [63]: 2
Out[63]: 2
```

I copy it from ipython-qtconsole using *ctrl+shift+c*, not from ipython-notebook...

It's hard to copy with prompts in ipython-notebook, while you can double click and select prompts, it's ugly when you paste to text editor then.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to upload a notebook to gist.github.com. It will render both input and output to HTML.

I usually include the key code directly in the answer, with a link to gist for context. For example: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44826732/81658) and [gist](https://gist.github.com/sbliven/bfa88fd1f4d3365f6d6170611945fa39)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855794/whats-the-best-way-to-share-jupyter-notebooks-with-non-programmers